# Nesting Repeater Throws Casting Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I currently have a parent repeater and two child repeaters on my page. I am wanting to dynamically pull data from our database and display them within the repeaters. I followed the Microsoft guide and a few SO questions on how to do this, and this is what I have arrived at:

```
<!-- start parent repeater -->
    <asp:repeater id="parentRepeater" runat="server">
       <itemtemplate>
          <li><div id="et_<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"EquipmentTypeName") %>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"EquipmentTypeName") %><label><input type="checkbox"></label></div><ul runat="server">

          <!-- start child repeater1 -->
          <asp:repeater id="Repeater1" datasource='<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem).Row.GetChildRows("myrelation") %>' runat="server">

             <itemtemplate>
                 <li><div id="et_<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "[\"MakeID\"]")%>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "[\"MakeID\"]")%><label><input type="checkbox"></label></div><ul runat="server">
                     <!-- start child repeater2 -->
                      <asp:repeater id="childRepeater2" datasource='<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem).Row.GetChildRows("myrelation2") %>' runat="server">

                         <itemtemplate>
                             <li><div id="et_<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "[\"YearID\"]")%>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "[\"YearID\"]")%><label><input type="checkbox"></label></div><ul runat="server">
                         </ul></li></itemtemplate>

                      </asp:repeater>
                      <!-- end child repeater2 -->
             </ul></li></itemtemplate>

          </asp:repeater>
          <!-- end child repeater1 -->  

       </ul></li></itemtemplate>
    </asp:repeater>
    <!-- end parent repeater -->
```

And the code behind is as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create the connection and DataAdapter for the Authors table.
        string Connection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["md_dbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(Connection);
        SqlDataAdapter cmd1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from EquipmentType", cnn);

        //Create and fill the DataSet.
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        cmd1.Fill(ds, "EquipmentType");

        SqlDataAdapter cmd2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Make", cnn);
        cmd2.Fill(ds, "Make");

        //Create a second DataAdapter for the Titles table.
        SqlDataAdapter cmd3 = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct MakeID, TypeID, YearID from Parts", cnn);
        cmd3.Fill(ds, "Parts");

        //Create the relation bewtween the Authors and Titles tables.
        ds.Relations.Add("myrelation",
        ds.Tables["EquipmentType"].Columns["EquipmentTypeID"],
        ds.Tables["Parts"].Columns["TypeID"]);

        ds.Relations.Add("myrelation2",
        ds.Tables["Make"].Columns["MakeID"],
        ds.Tables["Parts"].Columns["MakeID"]);

        //Bind the Authors table to the parent Repeater control, and call DataBind.
        parentRepeater.DataSource = ds;
        Page.DataBind();

        //Close the connection.
        cnn.Close();
    }
```

If I load the page with only one child repeater, everything works fine, I get the correct data displaying, but when I add the second child repeater in, I get the following error message: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRow' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'. This fires on the`datasource='<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem).Row.GetChildRows("myrelation2") %>'` ASP line.

The tables that I am trying to pull from are structured this way:

EquipmentType

EquipmentTypeID | EquipmentTypeName

Make

MakeID | MakeName

Year

YearID

Parts

PartID | MakeID | YearID | TypeID

Each table references the Parts table.

More or less what I want the repeater to do is display all of the EquipmentTypes, then only display the make is we have a part for it in the database. Once the make is selected, then only display the year that we have parts for that make and equipmenttype in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to cast it to DataRow:

```
<%# ((DataRow)Container.DataItem).GetChildRows("myrelation2") %>
```

Comment: If I cast it this way, there is no error message, but the repeater does not load with any data.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else experiencing this issue. It could be that there is a missing tag at the top of the page. <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>